# How to stop multiple calls of the same query using React-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am using React-query for my React app.

I have `useLogin` and `useLogout` hooks which use `useQuery`:

```
export const useLogin = (input?: LoginWithEmailPassword) => {
  const { data, isLoading, isSuccess, error } = useQuery(
    ["loginWithEmailPassword"],
    () => loginWithEmailPassword(input),
    {
      enabled: !!input,
    }
  );

  return { data: data?.data, isLoading, isSuccess, error };
};

export const useLogout = (accessToken?: string) => {
  const { isSuccess, isLoading, error } = useQuery(
    ["logout"],
    () => logout(accessToken),
    {
      enabled: !!accessToken,
    }
  );

  return { isSuccess, isLoading, error };
};
```

In my AuthProvider; where I use the 2 hooks, I also have a `login` and `logout` function which will be called when a user clicks login/logout.

Given React-query's declarative approach, I'm also keeping 2 states; `loginInput` and `logoutInput`

```
AuthProvider.tsx

  const [loginInput, setLoginInput] = useState<LoginWithEmailPassword>();
  const [logoutInput, setLogoutInput] = useState<string | undefined>();

  const { data, isSuccess: isLoginSuccess, isLoading } = useLogin(loginInput);
  const {...} = useLogout(logoutInput);

  const login = (input: LoginWithEmailPassword) => {
    setLoginInput(input);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setLogoutInput(data?.accessToken);
  };
```

This issue I've found is that after the user clicks login and set's the `loginInput` state; `useLogin` will run. But `useLogin` will re-run every time the component re-rerenders because `loginInput` will still have the state; i.e. if a user clicks `logout`, `useLogin` will run again. What would be the best way to resolve this?

Things will be more straightforward if React-query has a `useLazyQuery` like Apollo.

A hacky approach I can think of is to reset the `loginInput` state to `undefined`, like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
if(isLoginSuccess && !isLoading && !!data) setLoginInput(undefined)
},[isLoginSuccess])
```

Comment: Perhaps this may help you https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries?from=reactQueryV3&original=https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries

You basically pass an 'enabled' boolean to your useQuery and it will run only if the boolean is true.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. But the issue is once a state is set with a variable, it will remain in state and it will fire that query on every re-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`login` and `logout` are not queries, but [mutations](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/mutations). They are not idempotent - you can't run them at will. They change some state on the server (logging the user in) or create a resource (a login token).

So, the answer is: don't use queries here.

Comment: Hi, this is a REST api, not GQL

Comment: that doesn't matter? You'd still want `useMutation` for this

Comment: I see, I didn't know React-query had this, now it makes more sense. Thanks :)